# How to share 'r' plots over http

Tags: r, http

To share an 'r' plot I first convert it to an image and then share it via email, shared folder etc... Is there an alternative method for sharing 'r' plots over the web. So a user can visit a dashboard and view crated 'r' plots via their browser ?

Comment: Have you tried publishing to RPubs via RStudio?

Comment: Easiest way might be to use `R2HTML` to generate output and save that output to a shared folder (e.g., Dropbox).

Comment: [googleVis](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleVis/index.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `shiny`

http://shiny.rstudio.org/

[image]